# Focusing a sun-powered death ray

Tags: optics

There is an abundance of Youtube clips showing vloggers using parabolic mirrors to focus the sun's energy to a point that can burn wood and melt metal.  These projects all have a pretty glaring (pun not intended) flaw: the range of the "death ray" is fixed.  Objects will only burn if they are placed in exactly the focal point of the mirror.

My friend and I have been debating how/whether a system of lenses could be used to adjust the focus of the solar death ray.  We have been sketching and googling diagrams of projectors and telescopes, but we're at an impasse.

**Is it possible to build a solar collector parabolic mirror that can be adjusted to burn objects at different ranges?  If so, what arrangement of lenses would make this possible?**

Comment: Short answer is, No. It is not possible to concentrate sunlight (or, the light from any other [_extended light source_](https://kids.britannica.com/students/assembly/view/229835)) into a laser-like beam using only lenses and/or mirrors. The proof is more complicated than I can understand, but I think you will find it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etendue#Conservation_of_etendue

Comment: @SolomonSlow  Thank you for your comment.  Perhaps I should have been more clear: I'm not looking for a laser-like beam.  I understand the reflected sunlight will have a focal point.  I looking for an arrangement of lenses that could be used to adjust that focal point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put a diverging lens in between the concave mirror and its focal point. Depending on the power of the diverging lens, you should be able to chose a point on the optic axis so that original parallel rays coming onto the mirror, rather than converging toward its focal point, can be made to pass through the diverging lens more or less parallel on its other side.

The idea then would be to put another convex lens on the other side of the diverging lens, so that these now parallel rays can be used to focus on the focal point to the right of the convex lens.

The main idea is that the convex lens should be able to move back and forth on some track or rail controlled by you, so that you can move the actual point where you need the suns light rays converge.

This way the light should be able to be focused on any point.

Comment: Thank you!  So concave mirror reflects light onto the diverging lens, and then diverging lens reflects the light onto a convex lens which is laterally adjusted to alter the focal point.  Does it matter what kind of surface is on the reverse side of the convex lens?

Comment: That's right. Note that the focal point is a property of the lens and that by moving the lens, you are moving the point where light is focused. I'm not sure what you mean by "_what kind of surface is on the reverse side of the convex lens_". Can you elaborate? Thanks.

Comment: So when you say the lens is "concave", I understand that to mean that the surface the light will hit is concave.  What is the shape of the surface of the lens from which the light leaves?  For example, a plano-concave lens is concave on one side and flat on the other.  A bioconcave lens is concave on both surfaces. Apologies if I'm using this terminology all wrong!

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. I guess the diverging lens can be anyone of these. Concave-flat or concave-concave. The important thing is that it must cause the original light reflecting off the mirror to end up parallel before it enters the final convex lens. That is, it goes from converging mirror->diverging parallel->convex focused. The last convex lens needs the ability to move forward/backward to adjust the point you want to heat/destroy :) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't looking to make a "laser" out of the sun's rays, but if you assume the sun's rays are parallel (which is a good approximation), then you could theoretically collimate them into any width you want using the below arrangement of mirrors. The light rays would come directly downwards, from North to South, and each mirror is a parabola with a shared focus of the black dot.
[image: Parabolic Reflectors]